# findOne returns a null object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, orm

I'm trying to find and delete a subdocument by `_id`, but it always returns null.

This is my `User` schema:

```
// Create sub-document schema for items

var itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  type: String, 
  colour: String, 
  material: String,
  brand: String,
  _id: String,
})

// Main user schema (incl. wardrobe)

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  password: String,
  passwordResetToken: String,
  passwordResetExpires: Date,

  facebook: String,
  twitter: String,
  google: String,
  github: String,
  instagram: String,
  linkedin: String,
  steam: String,
  tokens: Array,

  profile: {
    name: String,
    gender: String,
    location: String,
    website: String,
    picture: String
  },

  wardrobe: {
    items: [[itemSchema]]
  }

}, { timestamps: true });
```

This is an example object:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5c16d181c15a68c14fe2f2d3"
    },
    "wardrobe": {
        "items": [
            [
                {
                    "type": "T-shirt",
                    "colour": "Black",
                    "material": "Wool",
                    "brand": "Adidas",
                    "_id": "5c1827dcc13025f86gfdf053"
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    "type": "T-shirt",
                    "colour": "Black",
                    "material": "Cotton",
                    "brand": "Puma",
                    "_id": "5c1827dfc13025f86dfaf075"
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "tokens": [],
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "$2a$10$tyCl4frHgAA1m8p6Y6kAkeAbjdYK1SJ5ghnlvWCF/MAb9.hMfR2/a",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2018-12-16T22:28:17.777Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2018-12-17T23:10:02.301Z"
    },
    "__v": 16,
    "profile": {
        "gender": "",
        "location": "",
        "name": "Test",
        "website": ""
    }
}
```

and this is how I use `findOne`:

```
exports.deleteItem = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({"wardrobe.items._id": "5c1827dfc13025f86dfaf075"}, (err, item) => {
    console.log(item);
    if (err) {
        return console.log("error: " + err);
      }
      res.redirect('/wardrobe');      
    });
  };
```

`console.log(item)` always returns null, even though the id field is an existing document. Any ideas?

Comment: can you please add the documents in your mongo for more info?

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, iturns out `$elemMatch` is what I needed. This returns the entire object:

```
exports.deleteItem = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({ 'wardrobe.items': { $elemMatch: { "_id": "5c1985359db5074cb3da562d",} } }, {wardrobe:1}, (err, item) => {
    console.log(item);
    if (err) {
        return console.log("error: " + err);
      }
      res.redirect('/wardrobe');      
    });
  };
```

However I don't want the entire object, I want the specific object with the `_id` searched for. But that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
exports.deleteItem = (req, res, next) => {
    User.findOne({"wardrobe.items[0]._id": "5c1827dfc13025f86dfaf075"}, (err, item) => {
    console.log(item);
    if (err) {
        return console.log("error: " + err);
      }
      res.redirect('/wardrobe');      
    });
  };
```

`wardrobe` is an object but `items` is an array so you should go first item

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work. `console.log(item)` still returns null.

Comment: `{wardrobe.items[0]._id: "5c1827dfc13025f86dfaf075"}` it is last one. Can you try please?

Comment: No luck. With this, I get: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`

Comment: in the example document, the subdocument is nested in two array. It should be the reason, try with `{wardrobe. items[0] [0] ._id}`